# How to make the extent of a brush match the size of the parent element?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to combine `d3-brush` with `d3-zoom` in a force-directed graph. Although I managed to combine the modules, it seems that I am not able to use the brush on the whole `g` element which contains the nodes.Thus, I am not able to select all the nodes in the graph.

I have already had a look at some blocks, e.g. [D3 Selectable Force-Directed Graph](http://bl.ocks.org/pkerpedjiev/0389e39fad95e1cf29ce),https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4566102, [D3v4 Selectable, Draggable, Zoomable Force Directed Graph](https://bl.ocks.org/pkerpedjiev/f2e6ebb2532dae603de13f0606563f5b) which try to combine the two modules [[1](http://bl.ocks.org/pkerpedjiev/0389e39fad95e1cf29ce), [3](https://bl.ocks.org/pkerpedjiev/f2e6ebb2532dae603de13f0606563f5b)] or use the brush event in a force-directed graph [[2](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4566102)]. Moreover,  I have also read the [d3-brush API](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/blob/master/README.md#brush). However, I can not achieve the desired behavior.

The user can select a region of points in the graph by holding the **ctrl** key and pressing the **left mouse button** (**ctrl key + lmb**).

Theoretically, the user should be able to select all the nodes within the `g` element which contains the nodes. In the next figure you can see the maximum brush extent. Nodes outside the brush extent can not be selected.

[image: maximum brush extent]

In the figure below, you can see the DOM hierarchy of the HTML document.

[image: DOM hierarchy]

I am suspecting that the extent of the brush is not defined correctly, which causes this issue.If I apply the brush to the `svgForce` element and the nodes are also drawn directly on the `svgForce` element, then the brush extent matches the dimensions of the `svg`. However, in that case, the zoom does not work properly, because it is not bound to a `g` element.

```
svgForce.append("g")
.attr("class", "brush")
.call(d3.brush().on("brush", brushed));
```

Do you have any ideas what might be going wrong?

```js
var width_network = 700,
 height_network = 700,
    gForce,
    gMain,
    zoom,
    brush,
    CIRCLE_RADIUS = 10,
    link, 
    node, 
    nodeLabel,
    gBrush;

var network = {"nodes":[{"name":"A"},{"name":"B"},{"name":"C"},{"name":"D"},{"name":"E"},{"name":"F"},{"name":"G"},{"name":"H"},{"name":"I"},{"name":"J"},{"name":"K"},{"name":"L"},{"name":"M"},{"name":"N"},{"name":"O"},{"name":"P"},{"name":"Q"},{"name":"R"},{"name":"S"},{"name":"T"},{"name":"U"},{"name":"V"},{"name":"W"},{"name":"X"},{"name":"Y"},{"name":"Z"},{"name":"AA"},{"name":"BB"},{"name":"CC"},{"name":"DD"},{"name":"EE"},{"name":"FF"},{"name":"GG"},{"name":"HH"},{"name":"II"},{"name":"JJ"},{"name":"KK"},{"name":"LL"},{"name":"MM"},{"name":"NN"},{"name":"OO"},{"name":"PP"},{"name":"QQ"},{"name":"RR"},{"name":"SS"},{"name":"TT"},{"name":"UU"},{"name":"VV"},{"name":"WW"},{"name":"XX"},{"name":"YY"},{"name":"ZZ"},{"name":"AAA"},{"name":"BBB"},{"name":"CCC"},{"name":"DDD"},{"name":"EEE"},{"name":"FFF"},{"name":"GGG"},{"name":"HHH"},{"name":"III"},{"name":"JJJ"},{"name":"KKK"},{"name":"LLL"},{"name":"MMM"},{"name":"NNN"},{"name":"OOO"},{"name":"PPP"},{"name":"QQQ"},{"name":"RRR"},{"name":"SSS"},{"name":"TTT"},{"name":"UUU"},{"name":"VVV"},{"name":"WWW"},{"name":"XXX"},{"name":"YYY"},{"name":"ZZZ"},{"name":"AAAA"},{"name":"BBBB"},{"name":"CCCC"},{"name":"DDDD"},{"name":"EEEE"},{"name":"FFFF"},{"name":"GGGG"},{"name":"HHHH"},{"name":"IIII"},{"name":"JJJJ"},{"name":"KKKK"},{"name":"LLLL"},{"name":"MMMM"},{"name":"NNNN"},{"name":"OOOO"},{"name":"PPPP"},{"name":"QQQQ"},{"name":"RRRR"},{"name":"SSSS"},{"name":"TTTT"},{"name":"UUUU"},{"name":"VVVV"},{"name":"WWWW"},{"name":"XXXX"},{"name":"YYYY"},{"name":"ZZZZ"},{"name":"A1"},{"name":"B2"},{"name":"C3"},{"name":"D4"},{"name":"E5"},{"name":"F6"},{"name":"G7"},{"name":"H8"},{"name":"I9"},{"name":"J10"},{"name":"K11"},{"name":"L12"},{"name":"M13"},{"name":"N14"},{"name":"O15"},{"name":"P16"},{"name":"Q17"},{"name":"R18"},{"name":"S19"},{"name":"T20"},{"name":"U21"},{"name":"V22"},{"name":"W23"},{"name":"X24"},{"name":"Y25"},{"name":"Z26"},{"name":"A27"},{"name":"B28"},{"name":"C29"},{"name":"D30"},{"name":"E31"},{"name":"F32"},{"name":"G33"},{"name":"H34"},{"name":"I35"},{"name":"J36"},{"name":"K37"},{"name":"L38"},{"name":"M39"},{"name":"N40"},{"name":"O41"},{"name":"P42"},{"name":"Q43"},{"name":"R44"},{"name":"S45"},{"name":"T46"},{"name":"U47"},{"name":"V48"},{"name":"W49"},{"name":"X50"},{"name":"Y51"},{"name":"Z52"},{"name":"A53"},{"name":"B54"},{"name":"C55"},{"name":"D56"},{"name":"E57"},{"name":"F58"},{"name":"G59"},{"name":"H60"},{"name":"I61"},{"name":"J62"},{"name":"K63"},{"name":"L64"},{"name":"M65"},{"name":"N66"},{"name":"O67"},{"name":"P68"},{"name":"Q69"},{"name":"R70"},{"name":"S71"},{"name":"T72"},{"name":"U73"},{"name":"V74"},{"name":"W75"},{"name":"X76"},{"name":"Y77"},{"name":"Z78"},{"name":"A79"},{"name":"B80"},{"name":"C81"},{"name":"D82"},{"name":"E83"},{"name":"F84"},{"name":"G85"},{"name":"H86"},{"name":"I87"},{"name":"J88"},{"name":"K89"},{"name":"L90"},{"name":"M91"},{"name":"N92"},{"name":"O93"},{"name":"P94"},{"name":"Q95"},{"name":"R96"},{"name":"S97"},{"name":"T98"},{"name":"U99"},{"name":"V100"},{"name":"W101"},{"name":"X102"},{"name":"Y103"},{"name":"Z104"},{"name":"A105"},{"name":"B106"},{"name":"C107"},{"name":"D108"},{"name":"E109"},{"name":"F110"},{"name":"G112"},{"name":"H113"},{"name":"I114"},{"name":"J115"},{"name":"K116"},{"name":"L117"},{"name":"M118"},{"name":"N119"},{"name":"O120"},{"name":"P121"},{"name":"Q123"},{"name":"R124"},{"name":"S125"},{"name":"T126"},{"name":"U127"},{"name":"V128"},{"name":"W129"},{"name":"X130"},{"name":"Y131"},{"name":"Z134"},{"name":"A135"},{"name":"B136"},{"name":"C137"},{"name":"D138"},{"name":"E139"},{"name":"F140"},{"name":"G141"}],"links":[{"source":0,"target":1,"value":375},{"source":0,"target":2,"value":27},{"source":0,"target":3,"value":15},{"source":0,"target":4,"value":8},{"source":0,"target":5,"value":6},{"source":0,"target":6,"value":4},{"source":0,"target":7,"value":3},{"source":0,"target":8,"value":3},{"source":0,"target":9,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":10,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":11,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":12,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":13,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":14,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":15,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":16,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":17,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":18,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":19,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":20,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":21,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":22,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":23,"value":87},{"source":0,"target":24,"value":24},{"source":0,"target":25,"value":20},{"source":0,"target":26,"value":20},{"source":0,"target":27,"value":19},{"source":0,"target":28,"value":17},{"source":0,"target":29,"value":12},{"source":0,"target":30,"value":6},{"source":0,"target":31,"value":5},{"source":0,"target":32,"value":5},{"source":0,"target":33,"value":4},{"source":0,"target":34,"value":4},{"source":0,"target":35,"value":3},{"source":0,"target":36,"value":3},{"source":0,"target":37,"value":3},{"source":0,"target":38,"value":3},{"source":0,"target":39,"value":3},{"source":0,"target":40,"value":3},{"source":0,"target":41,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":42,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":43,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":44,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":45,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":46,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":47,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":48,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":49,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":50,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":51,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":52,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":53,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":54,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":55,"value":34},{"source":0,"target":56,"value":13},{"source":0,"target":57,"value":8},{"source":0,"target":58,"value":8},{"source":0,"target":59,"value":5},{"source":0,"target":60,"value":5},{"source":0,"target":61,"value":4},{"source":0,"target":62,"value":4},{"source":0,"target":63,"value":3},{"source":0,"target":64,"value":3},{"source":0,"target":65,"value":3},{"source":0,"target":66,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":67,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":68,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":69,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":70,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":71,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":72,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":73,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":74,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":75,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":76,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":77,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":78,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":79,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":80,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":81,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":82,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":83,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":84,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":85,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":86,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":87,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":88,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":89,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":90,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":91,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":92,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":93,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":94,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":95,"value":11},{"source":0,"target":96,"value":7},{"source":0,"target":97,"value":6},{"source":0,"target":98,"value":3},{"source":0,"target":99,"value":3},{"source":0,"target":100,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":101,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":102,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":103,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":104,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":105,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":106,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":107,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":108,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":109,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":110,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":111,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":112,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":113,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":114,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":115,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":116,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":117,"value":9},{"source":0,"target":118,"value":7},{"source":0,"target":119,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":120,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":121,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":122,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":123,"value":8},{"source":0,"target":124,"value":4},{"source":0,"target":125,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":126,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":127,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":128,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":129,"value":4},{"source":0,"target":130,"value":4},{"source":0,"target":131,"value":3},{"source":0,"target":132,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":133,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":134,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":135,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":136,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":137,"value":8},{"source":0,"target":138,"value":3},{"source":0,"target":139,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":140,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":141,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":142,"value":4},{"source":0,"target":143,"value":3},{"source":0,"target":144,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":145,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":146,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":147,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":148,"value":6},{"source":0,"target":149,"value":3},{"source":0,"target":150,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":151,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":152,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":153,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":154,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":155,"value":6},{"source":0,"target":156,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":157,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":158,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":159,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":160,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":161,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":162,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":163,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":164,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":165,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":166,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":167,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":168,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":169,"value":5},{"source":0,"target":170,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":171,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":172,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":173,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":174,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":175,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":176,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":177,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":178,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":179,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":180,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":181,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":182,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":183,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":184,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":185,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":186,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":187,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":188,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":189,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":190,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":191,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":192,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":194},{"source":194,"target":193},{"source":0,"target":195},{"source":195,"target":193},{"source":0,"target":196},{"source":196,"target":193},{"source":0,"target":197,"value":27},{"source":0,"target":199},{"source":199,"target":198},{"source":0,"target":201},{"source":201,"target":200},{"source":0,"target":194},{"source":194,"target":202},{"source":0,"target":195},{"source":195,"target":202},{"source":0,"target":196},{"source":196,"target":202},{"source":0,"target":204},{"source":204,"target":203},{"source":0,"target":206},{"source":206,"target":205},{"source":0,"target":208},{"source":208,"target":207},{"source":0,"target":201},{"source":201,"target":209},{"source":0,"target":194},{"source":194,"target":210},{"source":0,"target":199},{"source":199,"target":211},{"source":0,"target":213},{"source":213,"target":212},{"source":0,"target":214,"value":2},{"source":0,"target":216},{"source":216,"target":215},{"source":0,"target":218},{"source":218,"target":217},{"source":0,"target":218},{"source":218,"target":219},{"source":0,"target":204},{"source":204,"target":220},{"source":0,"target":194},{"source":194,"target":221},{"source":0,"target":194},{"source":194,"target":222},{"source":0,"target":208},{"source":208,"target":223},{"source":0,"target":225},{"source":225,"target":224},{"source":0,"target":227},{"source":227,"target":226},{"source":0,"target":229},{"source":229,"target":228},{"source":0,"target":230,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":231,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":232,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":233,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":234,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":235,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":236,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":237,"value":1},{"source":0,"target":194},{"source":194,"target":238},{"source":0,"target":194},{"source":194,"target":239},{"source":0,"target":194},{"source":194,"target":240}]};

zoom = d3.zoom()
 .scaleExtent([0.1, 10])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);
  
var container = d3.select("#network_group");

var svgForce = container
   .append("svg")
   .attr("id", "network_svg")
   .attr("width", width_network)
   .attr("height", height_network);

gMain = svgForce.append("g")
   .attr("class","gMain");

var rect = gMain.append('rect')
   .attr('width', width_network)
   .attr('height', height_network)
   .style('fill', 'white');

gForce = gMain.append("g");
      
gMain.call(zoom)
   .on("dblclick.zoom", null);
    
    
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(network.nodes).force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-200))
  .force("collision", d3.forceCollide().radius(CIRCLE_RADIUS*2))
  .force("x", d3.forceX(width_network/2).strength(0.015))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(height_network/2).strength(0.02))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width_network/2, height_network/2))
  .force("link", d3.forceLink(network.links).distance(70));
  
  
 var gBrushHolder = gForce.append('g');
 var gBrush = null;
  
 link = gForce.append("g")
    .attr("class", "force_links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(network.links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2);

 // define nodes
 node = gForce.append("g")
    .attr("class", "force_nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(network.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", CIRCLE_RADIUS)
    .on("mouseover", function (d) {
     d3.select(this).append("title")
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.name;
            });
    })
    .on("mouseout", function (d) {
     d3.select(this).select("title").remove();
    })
    .call(d3.drag()
     .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended));

 // define node labels
 nodeLabel = gForce.append("g")
  .attr("class", "label_nodes")
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(network.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .text(function (d) {
   return d.name;
   })
  .style("text-anchor", "start");
        
        
        
simulation.on("tick", ticked);
        
         
        
function ticked() {

            node.attr("cx", function (d) {
                return d.x;
            })
                .attr("cy", function (d) {
                    return d.y;
                });


            link.attr("x1", function (d) {
                return d.source.x;
            })
                .attr("y1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.y;
                })
                .attr("x2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.x;
                })
                .attr("y2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.y;
                });

            nodeLabel.attr("x", function (d) {
                return d.x;
            })
                .attr("y", function (d) {
                    return d.y - 13;
                });


        }

var brushMode = false;
var brushing = false;
var brush = d3.brush()
 .extent([[0,0],[width_network,height_network]]) 
 .on("start", brush_start)
 .on("brush", brushed)
 .on("end", brush_end);

function dragstarted(d) {
 if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
 d.fx = d3.event.x;
 d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
            if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
            if (d.fixed) {
                d.fixed = false;
                d.fx = null;
                d.fy = null;
                d3.select(this)
                    .style("fill","lightsteelblue")
                   .style("stroke", "#fff")
                    .style("stroke-width", "1.5px");
            } else {
                d3.select(this)
                    .style("stroke", "lightsteelblue")
                    .style("fill", "white")
                    .style("stroke-width", 9);
                d.fixed = true; 
            }
        }
              
        
function zoomed() {

 var transform = d3.event.transform;
  gForce.attr("transform", transform);
 }

if (network.nodes.length > 80) {
  zoom.translateTo(svgForce, (width_network - width_network * 0.4) / 2, (height_network - height_network * 0.4) / 2);
  zoom.scaleTo(svgForce, 0.4);
}

function brush_start(){
brushing = true;
node.each(function(d) {
            d.previouslySelected = ctrlKey && d.selected;
        });

    }

rect.on('click', () => {
        node.each(function(d) {
            d.selected = false;
            d.previouslySelected = false;
        });
        node.classed("selected", false);
    });

function brushed() {
  if (!d3.event.sourceEvent) return;
  if (!d3.event.selection) return;
  var extent = d3.event.selection;
  node.classed("selected", function(d) {
            return d.selected = d.previouslySelected ^
            (extent[0][0] <= d.x && d.x < extent[1][0]
             && extent[0][1] <= d.y && d.y < extent[1][1]);
        });
}
  
function brush_end(){

        if (!d3.event.sourceEvent) return;
        if (!d3.event.selection) return;
        if (!gBrush) return;

        gBrush.call(brush.move, null);

        if (!brushMode) {
            // the shift key has been release before we ended our brushing
            gBrush.remove();
            gBrush = null;
        }

        brushing = false;
    }

d3.select('body').on('keydown', keydown);
d3.select('body').on('keyup', keyup);

var ctrlKey;
    
function keydown() {
        ctrlKey = d3.event.ctrlKey;

        if (ctrlKey) {
            if (gBrush)
                return;

            brushMode = true;

            if (!gBrush) {
                gBrush = gBrushHolder.append("g").attr("class", "brush");
                gBrush.call(brush);
            }
        }
    }

function keyup() {
        ctrlKey = false;
        brushMode = false;

        if (!gBrush)
            return;

        if (!brushing) {
            
            gBrush.remove();
            gBrush = null;
        }
    }
```

```css
.force_nodes {
  fill: lightsteelblue;
}

.force_links {
  stroke: gray;
}

.force_nodes .selected {
  stroke: red;
}

.label_nodes text {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="network_group"></div>
```

You can find a working version of the code also in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8advzg5o/19/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code right now is that you're appending the brush group to a group that you later translate in the zoom function:

```
var gBrushHolder = gForce.append('g');
```

Instead of that, append the brush group to the main group:

```
var gBrushHolder = gMain.append('g');
```

Then, use a variable to track the zoom's translate and scale...

```
//declare it:
let currentZoom;

//update its value in the zoom function:
currentZoom = d3.event.transform;
```

Finally, use that value to get the SVG position of the nodes:

```
node.classed("selected", function(d) {
    return d.selected = d.previouslySelected ^
        (extent[0][0] <= (d.x * currentZoom.k + currentZoom.x) && (d.x * currentZoom.k + currentZoom.x) < extent[1][0] && extent[0][1] <= (d.y * currentZoom.k + currentZoom.y) && (d.y * currentZoom.k + currentZoom.y) < extent[1][1]);
});
```

Here is the updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uxqf7tp2/